# Assign atribute to a link using variable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm trying to assign an attribute "href" to a link using jQuery. The thing is my "href" value is the "src" value of another object. So my final code looks like this:

```
imgLink.attr("href", imgArray.eq(i).attr("src"));
```

imgLink is my "a" tag and imgArray is an array of "img". So I'm, on paper, asigning to my "a" tag an "href" attribute with value: `imgArray.eq(i).attr("src")...` But nothing works, I get this error: "`imgLink.attr` is not a function".

Anyone knows what's happening here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely `imgLink` is not a jQuery object. Try this.

```
$(imgLink).attr("href", imgArray.eq(i).attr("src"));
```

If `imgArray` is also not a jQuery object then convert that also into jQuery object.

```
$(imgLink).attr("href", $(imgArray).eq(i).attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your DOM elements in jQuery.

```
jQuery(imgLink).attr("href", jQuery(imgArray.eq(i)).attr("src"));
```